# cant set variable in windows batch for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

In a for loop reading a file line by line i would like to store the input parameter in a variable. In the below example I have reproduced the problem. I try to store **%%a** to a variable **text** but the variable remains empty.

if we assume that the file **OneLiners.txt** contains two lines of text

```
You won't drink away the alcoholism.
A liberal is just a conservative that hasn't been mugged yet.
```

and running a script like this

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (OneLiners.txt) do (
  set text=%%a

  echo %%a 
  echo %text%
)
```

will echo

```
You won't drink away the alcoholism.
ECHO is off. 
A liberal is just a conservative that hasn't been mugged yet.   
ECHO is off.
```

Indicating that the variable is empty. 
How is it possible to assign the content of the parameter to variable? I thought this was the way to do it.

Comment: Please search SO for `delayed expansion`. There are many articles on this matter - it #1 FAQ and get asked daily.

Comment: Thanks, it helps...  Hmm, then since this is the #1 asked question then maybe the problem lays within the batch interpreter and not the user.

Comment: Rather the interpreter of the batch rules!

Comment: Blame Microsoft for disabling it by default to ensure backwards compatibility.